# Python Can't Find Modules

Tags: python, homebrew, python-imaging-library

I'm running a python script which resizes and converts images to JPG and an RGB.  This script worked perfectly until I upgraded my computers HD and moved everything over from my Time Machine backup.  Now when I try to run the script it can't find any modules.  Specifically the Image module (I use Pillow).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "processImgs.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os, sys, argparse, shutil, imgFunctions
  File "/web/script/python/img_processing/imgFunctions.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os, sys, Image, shutil, re
ImportError: No module named Image
```

I am using Homebrew to manage my modules, and "brew list" outputs the following:

```
freetype    graphicsmagick  libpng      libtool     little-cms2 openssl     pkg-config  readline    webp
gdbm        jpeg        libtiff     little-cms  openjpeg    pillow      python      sqlite
```

If i run "pip list" I get:

```
Pillow (2.3.0)
pip (1.5.4)
setuptools (2.2)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

If i run "help(modules)" in python, the Image module isn't listed.

Comment: I think when you moved, symbol links lost, because `Homebrew installs packages to their own directory and then symlinks their files into /usr/local.`

Comment: I think you are in the right track Omid.  I found a PIL install that i compiled form source to try to make this work.  Pillow will not run with PIL installed, so I removed it.  Now I'm getting  "No module named Image".  So this is definitely a linking issue.  I have tried "brew unlink pillow" "brew link pillow" but that doesn't help...

Comment: So my question now is: How can I get Python to find my brew modules?  Running "which python" and "which brew" both have the same path, yet none of the modules are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be your python path isn't set up correctly after the move.

[see here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python) for the homebrew/python docs page and it seems that a reinstall of homebrew may fix it.

Comment: I uninstall and reinstalled homebrew.  The issue now is Python is not seeing ANY of the modules I'm installing with brew.  I installed python via brew and made sure I am using the correct version... it almost seems like brew isn't linking the modules to python.  Is there anything I can run to debug.  Brew doctor says everything is OK.

Comment: check your PATH environmental variable and make sure the directory containing your python files.  $(brew --prefix)/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages have to be in the sys.path for import to run correctly.